# Java how to print arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm kinda new to programming and I know that the problem is pretty simple.. but I couldn't figure it out..

Let's say that I'd like to create an arraylist like this ;
                  `String words [ ] = { } ;`      instead of         `ArrayList words = new ArrayList();`    or
    `ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();`

but the problem is...  when I want to add the words that we scan on the string that we created to the list ,  I get an error.. 
("Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type String[]
 ")  I've tried to use  Arrays.toString()     method.. but I guess there is 
something that I miss.. Could you guys help me out?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testing_Stuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence =("This is texting");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(sentence);
        String words [] = {};

        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            words.add((scan.next());

        }
        System.out.println(words);

    }
}
```

Comment: `String words [ ]` is an array not an `ArrayList`!

Comment: that's right.. my bad, I meant array..

Comment: You can not use methods on a primitive array. And a primitiva array has a fix size

Comment: As @Jens stated, you can't call the add method on an array - it doesn't exists. If you wanted to add an element to the array, you would have to create a new array with a size big enough to hold the element, or would have to have the initial array large enough to add more elements.

Comment: thanks for your comments.. how can I do that 
with the most efficient way?

Comment: @Parzival, if you use String words[] instead of ArrayList, you have to write the size of the array at the declaration time too. String words[] = new String[10]. Then to add or access the values inside the array you have to use the following syntax: words[n]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `add` method on an array which is not possible. Also, you have some syntax mistakes.

You can either define a length to the array from the start and add to it as follows:

```
String sentence ="This is texting";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(sentence);
String words[] = new String[sentence.split(" ").length];
int i = 0;
while(scan.hasNext()) {
     words[i++] = scan.next();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Or you can use a list as follows:

```
String sentence = "This is texting";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(sentence);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while(scan.hasNext()) {
     words.add(scan.next());
}
System.out.println(words);
```

In both cases the output would be:

```
[This, is, texting]
```